# Password field for pyforms?

Tags: python-2.7, passwords, pyforms

My UI is written in pyforms.

How can I implement a password field? (EG. instead of 'P@ssW0rd' it would display '********').

I have found that I can utilize QLineEdit.EchoMode, but unsure how to implement.

Thanks in advance!

- Updated to reflect community guidelines

Comment: Please update your question to be a question. It is not clear what you are asking for help with. Please review the guidelines here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and rephrase your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following module as `ControlPasswordText.py` in your project folder:

```
from pysettings import conf
from pyforms.Controls import ControlText

from PyQt4.QtGui import QLineEdit

class ControlPasswordText(ControlText):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ControlPasswordText, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.form.lineEdit.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)
```

And here's how you would use it:

```
import pyforms
from   pyforms          import BaseWidget
from   pyforms.Controls import ControlText
from   pyforms.Controls import ControlButton

# Importing the module here
from ControlPasswordText import ControlPasswordText

class SimpleExample1(BaseWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(SimpleExample1,self).__init__('Simple example 1')

        #Definition of the forms fields
        self._username     = ControlText('Username')
        # Using the password class
        self._password    = ControlPasswordText('Password')


#Execute the application
if __name__ == "__main__":   pyforms.startApp( SimpleExample1 )
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a bunch.  Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Pyforms also includes a password box. You can also use
`self._password = ControlPassword('Password')`

So simply:

```
import pyforms
from pyforms.basewidget import BaseWidget
from pyforms.controls import ControlText
from pyforms.controls import ControlButton
from pyforms.controls import ControlPassword


class Login(BaseWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Login,self).__init__('Simple example 1')

        #Definition of the forms fields
        self._username  = ControlText('Username', 'Default value')
        self._password = ControlPassword('Password')

        self._button     = ControlButton('Login')
        self._button.value = self.__buttonAction #Define button action

    def __buttonAction(self):
        """Button action event"""
        username = self._username.value
        password = self._password.value
        credentials = (username, password)
        return credentials

#Execute the application
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pyforms.start_app( Login )
```